# Java - System process listener

Tags: java, process, interface, listener, system

Is there any way I can get a system process and listen to it so I can get what it's doing? An example of what Im looking for is this:

```
RunningProcess proc = new RunningProcess("notepad.exe");
ProcListener procListener = new ProcListener(proc);
```

Listener class example:

```
public class ProcListener implements ProcessListener {

    public ProcListener(...) {

    }

    @Override 
    public void started() {

    }

    @Override 
    public void terminated() {

    }

    @Override 
    public void ioOperation(IOoperation iop){

    }

}
```

Is there something like that? I haven't found yet.

Comment: I think termination should be do-able, by waiting for a return value from the process in its own thread. IO should be do-able but with std input and output only by monitoring streams (unless you use native code and JNI or JNA).

Comment: My intention is to listen to running processes. If the process is not running yet, Listener would wait until it runs and notify "start".

Comment: ??? It would start when you tell it to start, no sooner and no later.

Comment: My intention is not to create or interact with processes but listen to them. Process class (example) creates an object of a system running process not a new process and then start it or kill it or whatever a process-related action. But if I created a new process and the run it, the ProcessListener would be the same.

Comment: Then you're likely SOL and should not use Java for this. Java was built to be as OS agnostic as possible and thus is a very poor tool for this sort of thing. What you're trying to do will require a language that can get extremely cozy with the OS. Look at C# if this is for a Windows platform, or C/C++ for same or anything else. If you must use Java, then you'll need to go beyond core Java with JNI or JNA or other utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your jar whenever another program is started or terminated, I recommend using [Bill2's Process Manager](https://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/download-en.shtml). Although this is not a Java way to do, it can launch a program or batch file when some processes started/terminated, and you can execute the jar using batch file. After installing, you may want to change the language in Options first. The software is simple and quite easy to use.